# change setInterval interval from 100ms to 50ms

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With my setInterval I add my data value 0.0152 in every 100ms after my data value becomes more than 1 I want 0.0152 to be added in every 50ms and i've no idea how, I wrote it but even if not working any solutions ?

```js
  data:{
    crashValue: 0,
  },
  mounted(){
    setInterval(this.crashFunction,100);
  },
  methods:{
    crashFunction: function() {
      this.crashValue += 0.0150;
      if(this.crashValue == 1){
        setInterval(this.crashFunction,50)
      }
    },
  }
```

```html
<h2 class="crashNumber">{{ crashValue.toFixed(2) }}x</h2><br />
```

Comment: At very low intervals, the function isn't super accurate. You might be facing that issue

Comment: Splitting your paragraph into phrases may improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially write it using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, dodging the problem of clearing the original timer:

```js
data: {
  crashValue: 0,
},
mounted () {
  this.startTimer();
},
methods: {
  crashFunction () {
    this.crashValue += 0.0150; // Should this be 0.0150 or 0.0152?
    this.startTimer();
  },
  startTimer () {
    setTimeout(this.crashFunction, this.crashValue > 1 ? 50 : 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the old interval timer when you start the new one. So you need to save the timer in a variable.

You should check that you're actually crossing the threshold, so you need to check that the old value of `crashValue` is less than 1 and the new value is at least 1. `this.crashValue == 1` is never going to happen because 1 isn't a multiple of `0.015` (and you should also avoid using `==` with floating point, because of roundoff errors).

```
data:{
    crashValue: 0,
    timer: null
  },
  mounted(){
    this.data.timer = setInterval(this.crashFunction,100);
  },
  methods:{
    crashFunction: function() {
      let oldcrashValue = this.crashValue;
      this.crashValue += 0.0150;
      if(oldCrashValue < 1 && this.crashValue >= 1){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.timer = setInterval(this.crashFunction,50)
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: You don't need the `.data` or `.methods`, they're part of Vue and will be exposed directly via `this` instead. You also don't need to `bind` functions declared inside `methods`, Vue handles that automatically too.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use Vue so I didn't realize that. I've cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

Existing interval cannot be changed, only cancelled. As other answers explain, another 50ms `setInterval` or `setTimeout` should be set instead of 100ms when the time comes.

If intervals are multiples, this can be done with single interval that is a common denominator:

```
crashFunction: function() {
  if (this.crashValue < 1 && this.i % 2)
    return; // skip every second time 

  this.i++; // not tied to exact crashValue
  this.crashValue += 0.0150;
},
```